# How to keep reflection of HDRI on object with Glass material, but keep it transparent

Tags: shaders, export

I have sphere with complex glass shader. I want to have reflection of HDRI on it, but keep it transparent so we can see through, when I export animation as sequence of png pictures. I want this like on first sphere looking from left to right on the bottom of the second picture. You see how it has reflections of studio, but still you can see those patterns behind(you can see through sphere).

What I have is this on first picture, with reflection of hdri but not transparent. Is it about shader settings, or rendering?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cycles you can enable transparent glass option, which makes glass transparent in RGBA export

[image]

Comment: That was simple... Thanks man!

Comment: @Radoon Just be aware that this might look strange if you want to use colored glass and put it on a different background with the _Alpha Over_ node... colors become more or less grey.

Comment: Gonna render it and put it in unity as sequence of pictures. Thanks for tip!